# Use hash as source for collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following hash:

```
FIELD_LIST = {
  -1 => 'User',
  -2 => 'Duration',
  -3 => 'Price',
  -4 => 'Invoiced'
}
```

I want to use this with a collection_check_boxes.

In the manual it says:

> The :value_method and :text_method parameters are methods to be called on each member of collection.

So I tried this:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes TimesheetReport::FIELD_LIST, [0], [1], :input_html => { :class => 'checkbox' }
```

But that gives me an error.

How is it possible to use a hash as input to generate the checkboxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it is possible. A Hash is technically a collection of objects. You can do something like this:

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :field_name, TimesheetReport::FIELD_LIST, :first, :last, :input_html => { :class => 'checkbox' }
```

Replace `:field_name` with the actual name of your attribute where you want to store this data. It should work.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that you could do this. Great solution!